# AWS Cognito auto sign-in in WebView after app sign-in

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have an app using `aws-amplify` `withAuthenticator` HOC to manage the authentication process. It signs in correctly. Inside the app, I'm using a `WebView` to show the web page with a login (also using `withAuthenticator` HOC).

My goal is to skip or do auto sign-in for the WebView using whatever token or current cognito user in the app.

What's the preferred way in doing this?

Comment: I need to do the same thing. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @FrancoisNadeau ended doing API to check for existing user sessions. If there's none, redirect back to login.